# queries to get data in batches from a huge data table

Tags: java, sql, oracle, performance

I need to create some files with my own format(let say 5000 recs each) from a huge data table (May contain 5 Million records). And i want this creation to be multi threaded.

So how can I form queries efficiently to fetch records like 1..5000 and 5001..10000 and so on.

I can form some thing like select * from table where rownum<5000 and not exists ( already fetched records). But it is not the efficient one.

Please suggest the best way of forming the queries or any alternative approach to create files.

Comment: Check this out: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results

Comment: does each file have to have the same number of rows? as if its not important, you could divide the table into ROWID ranges and then each thread would just use something like `where rowid between A and B`.

Comment: Are you talking about creating 1,000 files? Do you need to write all of the rows to files?

Comment: Yes i am looking for same @DavidAldridge

Comment: How do you decide which record goes to which file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Oracle 11g you can use the DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE package to run your procedure in multiple threads.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_parallel_ex.htm#CHDIJACH).

If you're on an earlier version you can implement DIY parallelism using a technique from Tom Kyte.  The Hungry DBA provides [a good explanation on his blog here](http://hungrydba.blogspot.co.uk/2007/12/tom-kytes-do-it-yourself-parallelism.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a set of queries using the MySql `LIMIT` clause to implement paging (e.g. a query would get the first 1000, another would get the second 1000 etc..).

You could form these queries and submit as `Callables` to an [Executor service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) with a set number of threads. The `Executor` will manage the threads. I suspect it may be more efficient to both query and write your records within each `Callable`, but this is an assumption that would likely require testing.